# Bind to DOM event with GwtQuery

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

How to do this similar function with GwtQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test_div').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
        alert('Changed');
    })
})
```

I think the question here would be the right GWT DOM event to bind to with GwtQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly GQuery does not support those events. There is an [issue](https://github.com/gwtquery/gwtquery/issues/124) opened  to change the events mechanism used in gquery, and eventually this would fix this problem. Post a +1 in this issue adding this case or open a new issue.